# signature.verify always return false with received signature from c# code

Tags: java, c#

I am signing data from client side (c#) and verifying signature on server side using java.

here is my client code

---

```
          string csrHeaderAndPayload = Convert.ToBase64String(u8.GetBytes(csrHeader)).Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_') + "." + Convert.ToBase64String(u8.GetBytes(payload)).Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');
         byte [] output = signCsrData(csrHeaderAndPayload , privateKey);
          return output;

   protected byte[] signCsrData(string csrJSONData, RSAParameters privateKey)
    {
        byte[] csrData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csrJSONData);
       // byte[] hashData;
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCSP = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
       SHA256Managed hash = new SHA256Managed();

        rsaCSP.ImportParameters(privateKey);

        //hashData = hash.ComputeHash(csrData);

        return rsaCSP.SignData(csrData, hash.GetType());
    }
```

and server side code:
MOD and EXP sent from the client side, here it's verifying csrJSONData with csrHeaderAndPayload(signature sent from client).

---

```
    BigInteger mod = new BigInteger(Base64.decodeBase64(((String) jpkJson.get(MOD))));
        BigInteger exp = new BigInteger(Base64.decodeBase64(((String) jpkJson.get(EXP))));
        RSAPublicKeySpec rsaKeyspec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(mod, exp);
        publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(rsaKeyspec);

        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(SHA256withRSA);
        signature.initVerify(publicKey);
        signature.update((csrJSONData).getBytes("UTF-8"));
        if (!signature.verify(this.signature)) {
           return false
        }
```

This signature.verify always returning false.
Please don't close this question, have already seen solution in other post but nothing solves my problem.